# Who is the רא"ם

Tags: rishonim, tractate-nedarim

The Shitta Mekubetzes on Nedarim (8a) quotes the רא"ם.

Who does this refer to?

(My guesses for possible candidates are R. Eliezer of Metz, R. Eliyahu Mizrachi, and Ri Ibn Migash.)

---

Extra points to anyone who can locate the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be R. Eliezer of Metz, as Tosafos there s.v. mushba quote "R. Eliezer".

Comment: It seems simple enough. That would be the first place to look. So having answered it yourself do you get the points?

Comment: @cham Yes, but he has to wait two days until he's able to accept it, to give others a chance at an accepted answer. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ for more info.

Comment: @cham, he can accept his own answer, but he gets no reputation points for doing so.